# How to insert and shift buffer of stream in C++?

Tags: c++, stream

Let's just say I have an .ini file that looks like:

```
[material#3]
Diffuse=sometexture.jpg
Normal=someNormalMap.jpg
Specular=NULL
```

And I want to add a specular map value to the 'Specular' label, if I had this string buffer in a byte array I would do something like:

```
void assignSpecularMap(const char* name)
{
// Seek to position after 'Specular='
     int oldValueStrLen = strlen("NULL");
     int newValueStrLen = strlen(name);
     int shiftAmount = newValueStrLen - oldValueStrLen;
// Shift the entire buffer from after 'NULL' by the shiftAmount
// Write the new value after 'Specular='
}
```

The shifting of the buffer would be done with a memcpy. This is my naive understanding of how to write new values into a text file. If each entry or section isn't padded to a uniform byte size, which it never is for human readable and editable files, then any change in the entries for these files had to be accompanied by a shifting of the entire buffer, correct?

I'm wondering how to do this with a file stream in C++. It's not the case that the entire stream has to be loaded into a char buffer and do it the way I showed?

Comment: _"This is my naive understanding of how to write new values into a text file."_ Sorry that I have to confirm your naivity in that particular case. What you actually want is a simple grammar parser, which may be based on the whole text inpuit in form of line strings or even of a single string. The read write operations on the buffer level should be completely decoupled from that layer, as well as the final stream realization. That's what c++ formatted text extraction and output operators << and >> are for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you give me some extra info or links on how to do this? Or could you explain more about it? What do you mean by a grammar parser? Let's take the situation I described, you have 'Specular=NULL', how do you change that to 'Specular=sometexture.jpg'? Are you saying the shifting of the entire buffer when changing a value doesn't have to be done?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by _shifiting the buffer_?!? Reaing up to the next delimiting character for a portion of text?

Comment: If you want to replace one word in a big buffer of text and the new word doesn't have the exact same amount of characters (assuming ASCII) then everything after the replaced word needs to be moved, right? That's what I mean by shifting the buffer. If you have that buffer in memory and assuming you started off with one contiguous block for the text and needed to finish off with one contiguous block you'd need to make sure you have enough memory allocated and then memmove/memcpy everything after the replaced word. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I'd not try to change that in place in the stream direclty, that's my point. If you don't have to handle files containging amounts of gigabytes of data, you should read in the whould file, and represent it in appropriate data strutures internally. If data should be changed, you'll read in the file completely, manipulate the data structure (e.g. using a variable `std::vector<std::string> lines;`), manipulate the data, and write the file completely overwriting the original content. For anything else, you should consider storing the data in an appropriate database system.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see. Reading the entire file into your own data structures, changing the one you want and then writing it all out to a file again sounds tempting, but it's awfully inefficient, isn't it? Is this what databases do?

Comment: _" Is this what databases do?"_ Not really. Databases usually do what you mentioned first, they're working on blocks of physical data. But table row sizes (a table is a good candidate to manage in a single block), but with fixed row sizes for efficiency. Above of that you'll access tables and rows directly, where the DB system API does the mapping from the table schema (data types, and field lenghts) to your c++ data types